# Is there really a 6/8 meter with jazz swing?

Tags: jazz, meter

I recently started practicing jazz scales and rootless chords. I'm using very simple patterns: hit the chord, play up or down the scale with a swing rhythm. To give some musical context I'm playing in duple and triple meters. Normally I would include a compound meter like 6/8. But that seems to just be the aural equivalent of playing swing eights in duple meter. I.e. swing 2/4 = 6/8 or swing 4/4 = 12/8.

Is there some other way to think about 6/8 meter in jazz?

I'm glossing over straight eights in 6/8 in which case it would seem obvious the meter is compound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the two are very closely related, as a basic start point. Swing itself is that basically, but has categorically been noted as moving either way, depending on who's playing and what song it is. Tempo also has some bearing on the differential between the first two quavers and the third one in '6/8' time - aka swing 2/4.